# Write data scraped to text file with python script

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am newbie to data scraping. This is my first program i am writting in python to scrape data and store it into the text file. I have written following code to scrape the data.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
text_file = open("scrape.txt","w") 
url = urllib2.urlopen("http://ga.healthinspections.us/georgia/search.cfm?1=1&f=s&r=name&s=&inspectionType=&sd=04/24/2016&ed=05/24/2016&useDate=NO&county=Appling&")
content = url.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")
type = soup.find('span',attrs={"style":"display:inline-block; font-  size:10pt;"}).findAll()
for found in type:
  text_file.write(found)
```

However i run this program using command prompt it shows me following error.

```
c:\PyProj\Scraping>python sample1.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "sample1.py", line 9, in <module>
text_file.write(found)
TypeError: expected a string or other character buffer object
```

What am i missing here, or is there anything i haven't added to. Thanks.

Comment: Right now you're writing the html elements that you found. To get the string replace `text_file.write(found)` by `text_file.write(found.string)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check if `type` is `None`, ie `soup.find` did not actually find what you searched.

Also, don't use the name `type`, it's a builtin.

`find`, much like `find_all` return one/a list of `Tag` object(s). If you call print on a `Tag` you see a string representation. This automatism isn;t invoked on `file.write`. You have to decide what [attribute](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#tag) of `found` you want to write.

Comment: Thanks for the response, But if i remove the last two lines of code and write print type and run it in the cmd the it gives me output on command prompt which is basically an array having the data that i want to retrieve.

Comment: Also if i do print(found) inside for loop the it prints the data on cmd then why not writing into the file?

Comment: Updated with more info on `find`

Comment: thanks for the info u shared. I tried ur method my adding found.name inside the write. But in the text file i am getting only the tags printed and not the content that i need. Could u please help me getting that..

Comment: Thank u very much i found what i need here. I used unicode(tag.string) inside the write that helped me get the content

Comment: Hey one more thing, could u please tell me if i want to print the content of next tag to next line what am i suppose to do???

Comment: Not sure what you mean. `tag.string + os.linesep` maybe to add a newline char?